# iOS Firebase: Error Unable to generate keypair

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

In our ios Swift app we use Firebase Analytics. `(Firebase 3.16.0, Firebase Analytics 3.8.0, Firebase Core 3.6.0, FirebaseInstanceID 1.0.10)`

Our app gets background launched from significant location changes but can be launched and used normally in the foreground. Sometimes we see the following error and warning pop up multiple (a lot of) times in our log.

```
<Error> [Firebase/Messaging][I-IID010003] Unable to generate keypair.
<Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS020001] Failed to get InstanceID: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=-25308 "(null)"
```

It looks like those errors and warnings only pop up if the app was actually background launched by the SLC. Where do these errors come from?

**Note: Keychain Sharing is setup correctly**

thank you.

Comment: Have you found the cause of this error? I'm running into the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not. I contacted Firebase and after a long discussion they said they will have a look at it. I also provided an example project to prove this is reproducable. Haven´t heard from them for like 2-3 months. We just disabled Firebase logging in the background since it is currently OK for our use case. If you really want to have this fixed I suggest you create a bug on GitHub because the email support didn´t bring me very far. I hope you find a solution!

Comment: I see. Thanks for the update. I will let you know if I find a solution.